# Xamarin.Forms use current ContentPage as CommandProperty in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xaml-binding

I need the currently visible ContentPage, that is bind to a viewmodel, as a `CommandParameter` for a view model's command.

**Like:**

```
<Button Text="Save" 
        Command="{Binding AddObjectAndClosePage}" 
        CommandParameter={Binding MyContentPage} />
```

But Xamarin does not support the `ElementName`binding. How can I use now my ContentPage as parameter?

Comment: The method was a property of my view model :). But nevertheless I learned that this approach is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was completely my fault. 
My approach was breaking all rules of the mvvm pattern.

You can access the `Navigation`context in the command method in your viewmodel by writing:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

Lesson learned.

Comment: Consider using Prism, it exposes an `INavigationService`, that can be injected into your viewmodel and serves exactly that purpose.

Comment: @PaulKertscher thanks for the tipp. I ignored that, because I wanted to "understand" first the basics before adding external dependencies. But maybe this was the wrong way.

Comment: It's certainly good to understand the basics, but as soon as it comes to any real world project you do yourself a favour with Prism ;)

Comment: I got it :). Thanks for the tip.